# Sympy issue with solving equation from stated conditions

Tags: python, boolean, sympy

Hello I'm quite new to python and I'm trying to solve a set of equations with an unknown variable, the equations are in the code below

```
from __future__ import division
import sympy as sy
import math
#Global Variables indepenedant of calculations 
Tc = 9.25
Ic = 340*10-6
Tb = 6.2
I = 2 *Ic
alpha = 2*10**-2
thickness = 100*10**-10
L0 = 2.44*10**-8
electrical_resist = 0.5*10**-2
sigma = 1 / electrical_resist
k = sigma*L0*Tc
A = 1
B = 1
#set of problems to solve 
r0 = sy.symbols('r0')
LHS=(I/(alpha*thickness))**2 * electrical_resist 
RHS = -k*((r0**2)*((A*math.e**Tc)+(B*math.e**0)))+(alpha/thickness) * (r0**2) * (Tc - Tb) 
print sy.nsolve(LHS==RHS, 0.002)
```

But I keep getting an error

```
   2444         if isinstance(f, Equality):
   2445             f = f.lhs - f.rhs
-> 2446         f = f.evalf()
   2447         syms = f.free_symbols
   2448         if fargs is None:

AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'evalf'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`LHS==RHS` creates a boolean, True if LHS is exactly equal to RHS and False otherwise. `nsolve` and other solve functions in SymPy assume expressions are equal to zero, so use `nsolve(LHS - RHS, 0.002)`. See also http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html#equals-signs.